# Ajax function issue on return true and false in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, regex, wordpress

I am validating a form with ajax and jquery in WordPress post comments textarea for regex. But there is an issue when i want to alert a error message with return false. Its working fine with invalid data and showing alert and is not submitting. But when i put valid data then form is not submit. May be issue with return false.

I tried making variable and store true & false and apply condition out the ajax success block but did not work for me.

Its working fine when i do it with core php, ajax, jquery but not working in WordPress .

Here is my ajax, jquery code.

```
require 'nmp_process.php';

add_action('wp_ajax_nmp_process_ajax', 'nmp_process_func');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_nmp_process_ajax', 'nmp_process_func');

add_action('wp_head', 'no_markup');
function no_markup() {
    ?>    
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('form').submit(function (e) {
                var comment = jQuery('#comment').val();
                jQuery.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                    data: 'action=nmp_process_ajax&comment=' + comment,
                    success: function (res) {
                        count = res;
                        if (count > 10) {
                            alert("Sorry You Can't Put Code Here.");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });

    </script>
<?php
}
```

> And i'm using wordpress wp_ajax hook.

And here is my php code.

```
    <?php
function nmp_process_func (){
$comment = $_REQUEST['comment'];
preg_match_all("/(->|;|=|<|>|{|})/", $comment, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
$count = 0;
foreach ($matches as $val) {
    $count++;
}
echo $count;
wp_die();
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is with `return false`. returning false will stop ur form submitting. as far as i know, you want to validate with ajax and if its validated then you want to submit the form. right?

Comment: I think you should remove second `return false;`

Comment: Yes right. And when its not valid data then it should not submit the form.

Comment: i tried it. It is working fine with valid data but on the other hand when there is invalid data, its submitted too with alert .

Comment: what do you have in your `$matches` array?

Comment: first of all, if you use `post` as method you should use $_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST`. Second, jQuery han detect html, but preferes (as far as I know) `JSON` data. try to use in your php code something like `echo json_encode(array('count' => $count));`. Last but not least, could you add in your JS code, at the begining of the success function some debug stuff, like `console.log(res);` and update your question with that information. Note: if you'd add the json stuff to php you'd find the count in `res.count` on the JS side.

Comment: @madalin ivascu $matches array have the matching delimiters from the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I just figured it out by myself.

Just put `async: false` in ajax call. And now it is working fine. Plus create an empty variable and store Boolean values in it and then after ajax call return that variable.

Here is my previous code:

```
    require 'nmp_process.php';

add_action('wp_ajax_nmp_process_ajax', 'nmp_process_func');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_nmp_process_ajax', 'nmp_process_func');

add_action('wp_head', 'no_markup');
function no_markup() {
    ?>    
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('form').submit(function (e) {
                var comment = jQuery('#comment').val();
                jQuery.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                    data: 'action=nmp_process_ajax&comment=' + comment,
                    success: function (res) {
                        count = res;
                        if (count > 10) {
                            alert("Sorry You Can't Put Code Here.");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });

    </script>
<?php
}
```

And the issue that i resolved is,

**New code**

```
var returnval = false;
jQuery.ajax({
           method: "POST",
           url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
           async: false, // Add this
           data: 'action=nmp_process_ajax&comment=' + comment,
```

**Why i use it**

`Async:False` will hold the execution of rest code. Once you get response of ajax, only then, rest of the code will execute.

And Then simply store Boolean in variable like this ,

```
success: function (res) {
                        count = res;
                        if (count > 10) {
                            alert("Sorry You Can't Put Code Here.");
                            returnval = false;
                        } else {
                            returnval = true;
                        }
                    }
                });
                // Prevent Default Submission Form
                return returnval; });
```

That's it.

Thanks for the answers by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing a ajax call with a click event and if the fields are valid you submit the form:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery("input[type=submit]").click(function (e) {
                var form = $(this).closest('form');
                e.preventDefault();
                var comment = jQuery('#comment').val();
                jQuery.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                    data: {'action':'nmp_process_ajax','comment':comment},
                    success: function (res) {
                       var count = parseInt(res);
                        if (count > 10) {
                            alert("Sorry You Can't Put Code Here.");

                        } else {
                              form.submit();
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

note : you call need to call that function in php and return only the count!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of submitting the form bind the submit button to a click event.

```
jQuery("input[type=submit]").on("click",function(){
   //ajax call here
   var comment = jQuery('#comment').val();
   jQuery.ajax({
       method: "POST",
       url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
       data: 'action=nmp_process_ajax&comment=' + comment,
       success: function (res) {
             count = res;
              if (count > 10) {
                  alert("Sorry You Can't Put Code Here.");
                  return false;
               }else{
                  jQuery("form").submit();
               }
           }
      });
   return false;
})
```

Plus also its a good idea to put return type to you ajax request.
Let me know if this works.

Comment: so even if u r putting valid data, you cant submit the form?

Comment: form is submitted in both cases in valid or invalid data .,. In invalid data case alert is popup and when i click ok then the form is submitted.

Comment: Why used a click event on a button, if you can simply listen to the submitevent of the form. What if sombody submits the form by hitting enter in on of the input fields?